# Access data from selected element?

Tags: jquery, input, element

I've got two sets of inputs with IDs consist of a phrase and a number: A's (a1, a2, ...) and B's (b1, b2, ...).

**HTML:**

```
<input id="a1" value="1">
<input id="b1" value="">

<input id="a2" value="2">
<input id="b2" value="">
...
```

Now I want to extract the value of the A's, do someFunction(number) with it and paste the result into the value of the B's. Something similar to:

**JS:**

```
$( "[id^='b']" ).val( someFunction( $( "[id^='a']" ).val() ) );

function someFunction(n)
{
    return 5*n;
}
```

The result I get is:

**Result (JSFiddle):**

```
a1: 1
b1: 5

a2: 2
b2: 5
```

But I would like to get this:

**Result (What I want it to be):**

```
a1: 1
b1: 5

a2: 2
b2: 10
```

So if I could access the data of the element currently selected by jQuery, a possible solution could be:

- `$("[id^='b']").val(...)` sets the value of every B (b1, b2, ...)
- inside `val(...)`

  - get the `number` at the end of the id attribute of the element currently selected by jQuery
  - select the element with id `"a"+number`

So, how can I access the data from the element currently selected by jQuery? Or is there a better solution, I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cvngC/)

```
$("[id^='b']").val(function () {
    return 5 * parseInt($('#a' + this.id.replace('b', '')).val());
});
```

[this-keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: Works if the function is declared inside, like in the demo. But my function got a lot more lines of code and should be accessable global.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the problem with following code, so that my function is declared outside of jQuery:

```
$("[id^='b']").val(function()
{
    return someFunction($('#'+this.id.replace('b','a')).val());
});
```

Thanks to Tushar Gupta for inspiration.